# Как вытащить данные из Dictionary, который внутри Dictionary?

Tags: c#, коллекции

Есть такой тип `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>`.

Как вытянуть данные из внутреннего `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`?

Comment: Из какого конкретно внутреннего? Но вообще также как и любое другое значение из словаря — по ключу. Сначала достать нужный словарь по ключу из первого словаря, потом по ключу из второго. Если нужны все значение, то просто с помощью свойства `Values`

Comment: Если все - можно, допустим, сериализовать.

Comment: Приведите пример данных, которые хранятся в словаре и расскажите что именно Вы хотите получить. Так Вы скорее получите точный ответ, который делает то, что Вам нужно, а не то что нам показалось.

Comment: Чтоб не создавать такое `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>` надо использовать классы.

Comment: @Bulson бывает какой-нибудь Json десереализуется в такое, и не потому что я так решил, а потому что именно так оно и предназначено для десереализации. Не всегда создание классов будет удобно, и как альтернативу для удобства еще можно использовать алиасы типов `using MyDataItems = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,....`, чтобы потом объявить экземпляр модели данных как `public MyDataItems Items { get; set; }` и т.д.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Любую коллекцию можно проитерировать с помощью цикла.

```cs
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> dict = ...;

foreach (var pair in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    foreach (var innerPair in pair.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(innerPair.Key);
        foreach (string listItem in innerPair.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Если надо достать по ключу и проитерировать внутренний словарь, то вот так:

```cs
foreach (var pair in dict["key1"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    foreach (string listItem in pair.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(listItem);
    }
}
```

Если надо проитерировать внутренний список конкретного вложенного словаря, то вот так:

```cs
foreach (string listItem in dict["key1"]["key2"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(listItem);
}
```

Если надо получить конкретный элемент конкретного внутреннего списка, то как-то так:

```cs
string item = dict["key1"]["key2"][3];
```